# Is this lamp circuit correct?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, parallel, series

[image: Electronic Circuit]
Given the following circuit... Is this correct? Could D and A be considered parallel? (I'm trying to set up light bulbs A and D in parallel. B and C in series.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Bulbs only have 2 terminals; A and D in the schematic are ambiguous.

Comment: Hmmm, I see. So that means I must have a node that will split the electricity before it reaches the light bulb.

Comment: no, it's not. you can run series or parallel; this is some of both

Comment: No you can make the junction at the bulb terminal but you need to indicate whether the horizontal wires in your schematic are joined to the upper or lower terminal of lamps A and D - it can't be both or it would short the bulbs out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a lot of ambiguity in your question.

But regardless, two pin devices are shown as two pin symbols, like lamps, as shown below.

As I say, your definition is ambiguous, so the schematic shown is only one interpretation of that.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5RHo4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>